# jupyter notebook formatting anova vs. summary.lm R

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, linear-regression

I am testing my linear regression model using anova and summary.lm. The first tests against the F-statistic while the second uses the t-test for each variable.

When I put the code into jupyter notebook, the anova table comes out looking really nice, while the summary table just looks like code output.

This isn't a huge problem, but it would be nice if the summary tables looked like the anova tables in my final document.

Here is my anova output
[image: jk]

Here is my summary.lm output
[image]

Comment: Check `broom` package and the command `tidy`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`print(anova(crimefit))`